# CIDetector memory usage seems to be growing indefinitely

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, face-detection

I'm using [`CIDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) multiple times and memory usage is growing for every image in a project that uses ARC.

```
NSArray* features = [self.detector featuresInImage:ciimage options:detectorOptions];
...
// some code dealing with features
features = nil
```

I see in Instruments that ref count of `features` is always +1. I noticed that if added

```
self.detector = nil;
```

then memory goes down substantially and no listing of `FaceCore` in instruments.

[image]

Any way the face detector isn't releasing its memory?

Comment: Which particular instrument are you using? To really get a picture of how much memory your app is using you should be using the Activity Monitor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CIDetector isn't releasing memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156330/cidetector-isnt-releasing-memory)