# Exception when reusing CIDetector

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, ciimage

While attempting to reduce computation time while detection faces using `CIDetector` I tried to reuse a single detector instance for multiple face detections, as recommended by Apple:

> This class can maintain many state variables that can impact performance. So for best performance, reuse CIDetector instances instead of creating new ones.

All worked fine until I began processing thousands of photos. Now, from time to time I get a random exception `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This doesn't happen when I don't reuse the detector but instantiate a new one every time.

Some relevant code snippets:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) CIDetector* faceDetector;

- (void)initialVals {
    NSDictionary *opts_context = @{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @NO};
    self.context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:opts_context];
    NSDictionary *opts = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh,
                        CIDetectorTracking: @YES,
                        CIDetectorMinFeatureSize: @0.15
                      };
self.faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:self.context options:opts];
```

}

I'm not sure but this question may be related to [CIDetector isn't releasing memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156330/cidetector-isnt-releasing-memory) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, at least partially by removing the flag `CIDetectorTracking: @YES` when creating the detector.

It eliminates the crash while compromising on functionality. Filed an official bug report.